# Update multiple documents and return all updated documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a way to update many documents at once using `mongoose` and return all the modified documents. I tried with setting `multi:true` in [update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update). It is updating all matching documents but not returning any. Then I tried with [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate). It is updating and returning only one document even if there are many matching ones. Yeah, the function name itself tells, it will update only one, still I tried. I could not set option like `multi:true` in `findOneAndUpdate()`. How can it be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Currently I don't think its possible in MongoDB to update multiple documents and return all the updated documents in the same query.

In Mongoose, the `findOneAndUpdate()` is based on the native `findAndModify()` method of MongoDB.

If you check the offical [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) of the `findAndModify()` method, its states that -

> The findAndModify command modifies and returns a single document.
>
> Although the query may match multiple documents, findAndModify will only select one document to modify.

Hence, you can not update multiple documents using `findAndModify`.

`update()` or `updateMany()` method on the other hand updates many documents with the `multi` flag but it only returns the [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresults-update) which looks like this -

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: Thanks @Jyotman for clarification. I will go for two different queries then.

Comment: Be careful. You will lose atomicity and could lose data here. What if a new document was added after you `find` but before you `delete`? That new document will be lost in the void forever...

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm too let, but I also face this same requirement as yours,

Here is what I apply in **Controller** to get the requirement done as yours by NodeJs...

```
export const updateManyData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updateAllData = await Model.updateMany({} , {$set: {status: "active"}});
        const sendToClient  = await Model.find();

        console.log(updateAllData); // => just updated status is here
        console.log(sendToClient); // your all updated result is here

        res.send('Update Many Post Successful!');
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Server Side Error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First  upate and then get as per Jyotmans answer.

```
const update = await Model.updateMany({
    condition: "value"
}, {
    "$set": {
        field: "value"
    }
}, {
    "multi": true
});
// res.json(icMessages)

const get = await Model.find({
    room: req.params.room
}).exec()
res.json(get)
```

Comment: Be aware that this is not atomic though. Unless you take other measures to prevent it, such as using a (distributed) mutex _everywhere_ you write to that collection, the collection might be modified in between the updateMany and the find operations.