# Mongodb UpdateMany with upsert=true. is there any way to identify modified records?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

we are using updateMany with `upsert` as `true`. the query responses with inserted object id and modified record count. is there any way to identify modified records?

we have MongoDB 3.6.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update multiple documents and return all updated documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246188/update-multiple-documents-and-return-all-updated-documents)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it, as a callback or promise then you will find all updated data array.

```
Model.update({
    'type': "newuser"
}, {
    $set: {
        email: "abc@gmail.com",
        phoneNumber:"0123456789"
    }
}, {
    multi: true
},
function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(err);
})
```